# TextView (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm writing `Android` app and have one question.

I have 44 `TextViews`.

I need to apply custom font to them.

Can I declare something like text1...text44

And apply font to them?

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct. I appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very known library that applies Font to every `Textview` you have.

Its called [Calligraphy](https://components.xamarin.com/view/calligraphyxamarin).

You can do int simply by doing this in you `Application`:

```
CalligraphyConfig.InitDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .SetDefaultFontPath("fonts/your_font.ttf")
            .SetFontAttrId(Resource.Attribute.fontPath)
            .Build());
```

And in your `Activity/BaseActivity`:

```
protected override void AttachBaseContext(Android.Content.Context @base)
{
    base.AttachBaseContext (CalligraphyContextWrapper.Wrap(@base));
}
```

You can specify and specific font for every font if you need to.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `TextView` and use it everywhere:

```
    [Register ("com.myproject.TextViewForeign")]
    public class TextViewForeign:TextView
    {
        public TextViewForeign (Context context) : base (context)
        {
            setTypeFace ();
        }

        public TextViewForeign (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context, attrs)
        {
            setTypeFace ();
        }

        public TextViewForeign (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base (context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            setTypeFace ();
        }

        public TextViewForeign (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base (javaReference, transfer)
        {
            setTypeFace ();
        }

        private void setTypeFace ()
        {
            Android.Graphics.Typeface tf = global::Android.Graphics.Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Context.Assets, "fonts/bpg_arial.ttf");
            this.SetTypeface (tf, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your TextViews are named Text1, Text2, etc, containing the same text then a incrementing number, you might want to try to do a for loop :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 44; i++) {
    TextView text = FindViewById<TextView> (Resources.GetIdentifier ("text" + i, null, PackageName));
    //Apply your font to text.
}
```

But I would recommend that you add your font file in your resource assets and apply it using AXML (no idea if easily feasible or not). Also, note that using a for loop in this case might be heavy stuff for smaller devices.

Comment: I try to do it like this

Comment: Typeface tf10 = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Font/HelveticaNeueLight.ttf");
                text.Typeface = tf10;

Comment: in this row is error: 
          text.Typeface = tf10;

Comment: Try using text.SetTypeFace(tf10);